# nth parent of each filtered element in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I have a requirement where I need to find out 4th parent for each filtered item from jQuery.

```
$("a.dropdown-toggle").filter(function() {
     return $(this).text().indexOf('ADD_DELET') > -1
}).parents().eq(4);
```

If the above filter function is returning single value , above code is working fine but if the filter function is returning more than one item. Above code is not working.

Comment: so you got lots of `<a class="dropdown-toggle"`'s and you want to find the 4th one (which happens to be the add/delete button)? why not use the selector to find the specific one or when doing something click etc use `this`?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone : thanks for the reply , Basically the need is to implement a search functionality where user will type the search string and that search string will be compared with all the Childs on this HTML page and show the corresponding parent name to users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.eq(4)` is selecting element 4 from all the parents of all selected dropdowns, not the 4th parent of each.

Use a `.each()` loop that adds the appropriate parent to a collection.

There's also no need to use `filter()`, you can use the `:contains()` selector.

```
let parents = $([]); // empty collection
$("a.dropdown-toggle:contains(ADD_DELET)").each(function() {
    parents = parents.add($(this).parents().eq(4));
});
```

It would be easier if you gave those parents a unique class, then you could use `.closest()`:

```
let parents = $("a.dropdown-toggle:contains(ADD_DELET)").closest(".classname");
```

This is more robust than counting parents, since it won't break if the organization is modified to add or remove nesting levels.